# Selector data- with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some checkbox with values that should filter the content of some div somewhere in the page and I am having some trouble getting those div's selected.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    
  /*here I hide all the div and then try to generate the correct selector to show 
  the div's that correspond to the checkbox selection*/
  
  $('div').hide();
  var listSelection = '';
  
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    if(listSelection == '')
      listSelection = $(this).val();
    else
      listSelection += ' ' + $(this).val();
  });
  
  /*here i fail in the selection of them*/
  $('[data-category="' + listSelection + '"]').show();
  
  if(listSelection == '')
    $('div').show();
});
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a">
  a
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="b">
  b
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="c">
  c
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="x">
  x
</label>


<div data-category="a b c"></div>
<div data-category="a b"></div>
<div data-category="x a"></div>
<div data-category="c a"></div>
<div data-category="b c x"></div>
```

Let's say I check a -> the result should be the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th div to show
 If later I check a and c -> the result should be 1st and 3rd div to show but does not show anything at all

Comment: _"Let's say I check a -> the result should be the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th div to show If later I check a and c -> the result should be 1st and 3rd div to show but does not show anything at all"_ Is requirement to show elements whose attributes _contain_ a checked value , or whose attributes _exactly match_ the checked values ? Given the description above , if `a` and `c` were checked ,  if the requirement were to show all elements whose attributes contain `a` , the first **4** div's would be shown -- not only first and  third . If possible , can clarify requirement ? Thanks

Comment: Sure I can clarify. Take a look to http://jsfiddle.net/xmof6nnz/9/ and you would see that each div has several categories. If you select "a" and "c" checkbox I want to show the "Fourth div". But since the order of the category in that div is "c a" and not "a c" the div is not showed

Comment: Requirement to show `div` whose attribute match , in any combined order ? , but _not_ individually matched against sibling elements containing _one_ of the values ? i.e.g., "c a" or "a c" can _only_ match "c a" _not_ "a b c" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take a different approach. I change data-category to classes. The rest of the changes are in the javascript.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {

    $('div').hide();

    var listFiltered =  $('div');

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
      
        listFiltered = listFiltered.filter('.'+ $(this).val());
      
    });
    
    listFiltered.show();
});
```

```html
<div class="a b c">First div</div>
<div class="a b">Second div</div>
<div class="x a">Third div</div>
<div class="c a">Fourth div</div>
<div class="b c x">Fifth div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

replace:

```
 $('[data-category="' + listSelection + '"]').show();
```

by

```
 $("div[data-category='valueSearch']").show();
```

PS: selector by atribute is:

```
 $("typeElement[prop/attr='valueSearch']")
```

Comment: Thank you John but it's not working. When I selected more than one checkbox is when the 'filter' does not work.

Comment: ahmmm.. try this

$('body input:checkbox').each(function(){
    if(listSelection == '' && $(this).is(":checked"))
      listSelection = $(this).val();
    else if($(this).is(":checked"))
      listSelection += ' ' + $(this).val();
  });

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfect.

Just add some value to div's. Like

```
<div data-category="a b c">Hello a b c</div>
```

Are your divs empty?

Comment: No, they are not empty, this is just a simple version of what I'm working on.

Comment: I used this on jsfiddle, shows and hides you divs just ok. http://jsfiddle.net/xmof6nnz/

Comment: Use with jquery  1.7.2 and onDomReady.

Comment: thank you. I've made some changes http://jsfiddle.net/xmof6nnz/9/ and now check "a" and "c" and you should technically see "Fourth div" but it does not show

Comment: or even you should also see "First div" since it also contains "a" and "c"

Comment: You are concatenating in a orderly fashion. So you have "a c" not "c a". that is why you don't see fourth div. You don't see First div because you should have a b c instead of a c.
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        if (listSelection === '') listSelection = $(this).val();
        else listSelection += ' ' + $(this).val();
    });
    alert(listSelection)